# Работа с видео - запись рабочего стола при помощи python

Tags: python, windows, видео, экран

При помощи чего записать видео с рабочего стола? MoviePy создает анимацию, opencv записывает видео с камеры, PIL делает скриншоты. Больше для винды ничего не нашел ...

Comment: ключевое слово здесь: `screencast`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Я хотел бы тебе порекомендовать для этой цели использовать FFmpeg вот тут можно прочитать более подробно: https://www.ffmpeg.org
Там куча возможностей и настроек.
Вот пример кода как я использую это у себя на винде:

```
import subprocess as subp
from os.path import join

log_dir = '' # путь куда положить файл с записью
CORE_DIR = '' # путь где лежит ffmpeg.exe
video_file = join(log_dir, 'video_' + id_test + '.flv')
FFMPEG_BIN = join(CORE_DIR, 'ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe')

command = [
    FFMPEG_BIN,
    '-y',
    '-loglevel', 'error',
    '-f', 'gdigrab',
    '-framerate', '12',
    '-i', 'desktop',
    '-s', '960x540',
    '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
    '-c:v', 'libx264',
    '-profile:v', 'main',
    '-fs', '50M',
    video_file
]
ffmpeg = subp.Popen(command, stdin=subp.PIPE, stdout=subp.PIPE, stderr=subp.PIPE)
```

Очень классная штука запускаешь в отдельном процессе и во время работы скрипта или еще чего либо пишется видео.
Только не забудь остановить потом данный процесс правильно.

вот код чтоб остановить:

```
ffmpeg.stdin.write("q")
ffmpeg.stdin.close()
```

Comment: +1 за использование ffmpeg, чтобы видео экрана получить. В сторону: не используйте `std*=PIPE`, если вы  не потребляете соотвествующий поток, иначе подвиснуть процесс может (когда соответствующий системный буфер заполнится). Если хочется просто [скрыть вывод, то следует `DEVNULL` использовать](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11269575/4279).

Comment: Я согласен с комментарием: Но дело в том, что мне надо этот соответствующий поток потом остановить правильно или видео файл не запишется корректно, для этого приходиться использовать std*=PIPE. По другому что то у меня не получилось. А вот stdout=subp.PIPE, stderr=subp.PIPE можно конечно и в DEVNULL было отправить.

Comment: "скрыть вывод" намекает, что `std*`  в моём комментарии это `stdout`, `stderr` (стандартный поток вывода и поток ошибок).

Answer (score 1):

Можно делать скриншеты и записывать их в видеофайл
Нашел у себя вот такой код

```
    import numpy as np
    import Image, ImageGrab, ImageOps
    import cv2

    while(True):
        printscreen_pil =  ImageGrab.grab()
        printscreen_numpy =   np.array(printscreen_pil.getdata(),dtype=uint8)\
        .reshape((printscreen_pil.size[1],printscreen_pil.size[0],3))
        cv2.imshow('window',printscreen_numpy)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    # Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
    #fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
    fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret==True:
    #        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

           # write the flipped frame
            out.write(frame)

            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break

    # Release everything if job is finished
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```